# Convert text(including style) getting in API to HTML in Angular 8

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I want to convert text received in API response to the html file with style.

my response:-

```
description: "<span style="color:green">SAVE Rs.150 </span> on your 1st Booking- Applicable for Weekdays' Slots"
```

I have tried this but not working. style is not applying.

```
<div [innerHtml]="coupon?.description"">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to sanitize HTML string.

**ts:**

```
constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

sanitize(): SafeHtml {
  return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.coupon?.description);
}
```

**html:**

```
<div [innerHtml]="sanitize()">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the same

Comment: If this post helps you, please accept my answer.